# Trotterized time-evolution with tensorcircuit

Tags: tensor-networks, trotterization, tensorcircuit

I would like to do a Trotterized time-evolution with Tensorcircuit of a spin-Hamiltonian and started with the example
https://github.com/tencent-quantum-lab/tensorcircuit/blob/master/examples/timeevolution_trotter.py

I have two questions about it:

1. What method it used to calculate the time-evolution? I can't find a source about it. Are you applying time-evolution block-decimation (TEBD)? If so, how can a truncate the state after applying a Trotterstep?
2. I assume that one can also add noise channel to the Trottercircuit and then simulate the time-evolution as in step 1. It this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked uses exact simulation (state vector evolution) without truncation. If TEBD is required, you can try to use `MPSCircuit`. And if noise  simulation is required, you can try `DMCircuit`